# Looking for a simple way to add/update information records with CraftCMS

Tags: craft3, craft-features, craft-pro

I'm looking for a simple way to save form data to a database and be able to access that information. I'm not sure if I should use the custom fields or an entry (or a custom table) and if creating a module is the way to go or another easy way to have my form post submit handled with PHP.

I was hoping for a simple example of a module for Craft but I'm not finding it.

For the sake of an example, I'd like to add and edit books in my library:

```
Book Type:
BookTitle - 50 characters
BookAuthor - 50 characters
BookSummary - 300 characters
Pages - Integer
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please read this and tell me if you would like to use `records` or `elements` to store your data. I'll show you the code depending on your choice/needs https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23859/database-structure-for-craft-3-to-import-from-external-source/23863#23863

Comment: Seems like elements is the way to go since I believe the customers will need access to the table.  However, there's going to be quite a bit of coding anyways so we may go with records since everything will be customized.  Without seeing the difference, I would go with elements.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information in the comments I'll provide an example how to save elements in Craft. I'll just show an example with an existing element type `Entry`. You can see how to create a custom element type well documented in the [docs](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/element-types.md)

You'll create a new `section` in your CP and add the required fields to the layout. In your case you'll need `title` (Booktitle), `author` (BookAuthor), `summary` (BookSummary) and `pages` (Pages)

```
// get the section and the entrytype
// when you know your section id and entrytype id you don't
// need this. You can get the Ids by looking at the URL in the
// when you edit them
$section = Craft::$app->sections->getSectionByHandle('books');
$entryType = reset($section->getEntryTypes());
// Create an entry
$entry = new Entry([
    'sectionId' => $section->id,
    'typeId' => $entryType->id, // or insert the required type id manually
    'fieldLayoutId' => $entryType->fieldLayoutId,
    'authorId' => 1,
    'title' => 'A cool title of a book',
    'slug' => 'a-cool-title-of-a-book', // <- not required
]);

$entry->setFieldValues([
    'author' => 'Me and Myself',
    'summary' => 'it was awesome',
    'pages' => 9000
]);

// Save the entry
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);

// in case there is something wrong..
$errors = $entry->getErrors();
```

When you are going to create your custom element type without a field layout your code could look like this

```
$book = new Book([
    'title' => 'A cool title of a book',
    'author' => 'Me and Myself',
    'summary' => 'it was awesome',
    'pages' => 9000
]);
// Save the entry
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($book);

// in case there is something wrong..
$errors = $book->getErrors();
```